# Controller to Directive and Directive to controller correct way of communcation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a page, which contains the `pageNavigator` with page display content. according to the user `click` on the appropriate buttons(links) I am updating the page.

I made the directive for :page navigator as 'docNavigation' and included with my `home` html.

Now i requre,

When page loads,

1. my doc page should show the `count` as what i mensioned in `homeController` and the `switch` case last should be set as `20` which i set in `homeController`.
2. when user interacts i would like to update the `count` in `homeController` to update the page content.

What would be the correct way to get this?

here is my directive:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("docNaviDir", [])
    .directive("docNavigation", function () {
        return {
            restrict : "E",
            replace : true,
            templateUrl : '/views/directiveViews/docNavigation.html',
            link : function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
               var count = 0;
                element.find('a').on('click', function () {

                    var Id = $(this).prop('id');
                    switch(Id) {
                        case 'first':
                            count = 1; //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'prev':
                            count -= 1;  //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'next':
                            count += 1;  //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'last':
                            count = scope.totalPages; //get from `homeController`
                            break;
                    }
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    count = count;
                })
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

my homeController:

"user strict";

```
angular.module("ngTenderDocument")
    .controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.count = 0; //pass to directive and update by user
        $scope.totalPages = 20; //pass to directive
    })
```

my View:

```
<doc-navigation></doc-navigation> //directive
<h1>This is from home! Now you start to count, count is : {{count}}</h1> //count need to show the appropriate updates here.
```

my Navi View :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a id="first" href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a id="prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a id="next" href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><a id="last" href="#">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I assume HomeController will be always on the screen?

Comment: Nope, that's only for `home.html` view depends.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: is the navbar always used on a screen where HomeController is available? If not, how are you planning on implementing this paging on the other screens?

Comment: actually this is a sub-screen of main screen. this screen has only `pagenavigation` with html content updated. (this page itself a content of another page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use an object definition and scope mapping like

```
$scope.page = {
    totalPages: 10,
    count: 4
};
```

then

```
app.directive("docNavigation", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        //use your url
        template: '<div>' + '<a data-type="first" href="">first</a>' + '<a data-type="prev" href="">prev</a>' + '<a data-type="next" href="">next</a>' + '<a data-type="last" href="">last</a>' + '</div>',
        scope: {
            page: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
            element.find('a').on('click', function () {
                //using hard coded ids in a directive is dangerous as there can be other elements with the same id
                var type = angular.element(this).attr('data-type');
                switch (type) {
                    case 'first':
                        scope.page.count = 1; //update to `homeController`
                        break;
                    case 'prev':
                        scope.page.count -= 1; //update to `homeController`
                        break;
                    case 'next':
                        scope.page.count += 1; //update to `homeController`
                        break;
                    case 'last':
                        scope.page.count = scope.page.totalPages; //get from `homeController`
                        break;
                }
                scope.$apply(function () {})
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yyjfbpos/)

Comment: I am applying like this, but not working : `scope.$apply(function () {
this.page.count = count;});`

Comment: Still i am getting error as 'Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined'

Comment: @3gwebtrain why are you doing that.. the code above is working without it

Comment: No, I updated as like your suggestion. still getting issue as above said.

Comment: sorry Arun, my mistake, I didn't properly update your `scope-page-count` assignment correct. by the way why we need 'scope.$apply(function(){})`..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain it is because we are making the scope related changes outside of the angular digest cycle.... so we need to tell angularjs to run its watches manually... that is done by `scope.$apply()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76323/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided in the other answer are correct, namely you can pass in a variable to your directive.

I'd like to point out though you're mixing up vanilla and AngularJS. In your directive you're attaching a click event handler outside of Angular's awareness, which will lead to issues later on. Therefore, I suggest updating your directive code to:

```
app.directive("docNavigation", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/views/directiveViews/docNavigation.html',
        scope: {
            page: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            scope.goToPrevious = function(){
                 scope.page.count -= 1;
            };

            scope.goToNext = function(){
                scope.page.count += 1;
            };

            scope.goToFirst = function(){
                scope.page.count = 1;
            };

            scope.goToLast = function(){
                scope.page.count = scope.page.totalPages;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then update your template to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a ng-click="goToFirst()" href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="goToPrevious()" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="goToNext()" href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="goToLast()" href="#">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes I agree, But I thougt of playing much better with `jQuery` instead of `angular` lite.

Comment: but in the `link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {` what does the `controller`? can we use `controller` too..?

Answer (score 0):

Use isolated scope and pass count value to it from directive attribute. Inside isolated scope you need to mention `scope: { count: '=' },` which will perform two way binding with controller variable specified in `count` attribute with the `directive` count variable.

**Markup**

```
<doc-navigation count="count"></doc-navigation>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module("docNaviDir", [])
    .directive("docNavigation", function () {
        return {
            restrict : "E",
            replace : true,
            scope: {
              count: '=' //specified two way binding here
            },
            templateUrl : '/views/directiveViews/docNavigation.html',
            link : function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                element.find('a').on('click', function () {
                    var count = 0;
                    var Id = $(this).prop('id');
                    switch(Id) {
                        case 'first':
                            count = 1; //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'prev':
                            count -= 1;  //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'next':
                            count += 1;  //update to `homeController`
                            break;
                        case 'last':
                            count = scope.totalPages; //get from `homeController`
                            break;
                    }
                    scope.count = count;
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: My view is not updates... I guess this part is not woring : 'scope.$apply(function () {
      count = count;
     });'